# Solving coupled ODE's with gsl in c++

Tags: c++, gsl

I have to solve a set of three coupled second order Ordinary differential equations using gsl in cpp. I could not get any examples on the gsl site to solve coupled ODE's. I am completely new to gsl. Can someone please refer me to some examples for the same.

Thank you